# Linkage of two circles in $\mathcal{R}^3$

Tags: geometry, algebraic-topology

Is there an easy analytic expression to determine whether two circles two circles (of equal radius) in $\mathcal{R}^3$ are linked?

I guess one could look at their supporting planes, compute the intersection line of thise two planes and then conclude something about the linkage, but is there maybe a more direct way?

Comment: See Gauss's integral definition of linking number. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linking_number

Comment: This is not an ''analytic expression'' but you could consider the fundamental group of the complement of the circles in $\mathbb{R}^3$. This is explained in Chapter 1 ''The Idea of the Fundamental Group
'' of Allen Hatcher's book on algebraic topology.